# waitress command line returning "Malformed Application" when deploying flask web app

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I'm attempting to deploy a simple web app, and I'm using command line `waitress-serve --call` command. But every time, the command immediately returns `1. Malformed application 'name_of_project_here'`.

Here's my flask web app in python:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

and the command I run is just

```
waitress-serve --call "name_of_project"
```

I did try looking through the documentation, and I found where the error occurs, but couldn't find an explanation of why it's occurring. What does malformed application mean?

Comment: what you have as "name_of_project"?  It should be "filename:function_name"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minimal working example:

If you put code in file `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return "Hello World!"

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

then you can run it as

```
waitress-serve --call "main:create_app"
```

So `"name_of_project"` has to be `"filename:function_name"` which creates `Flask()` instance.

It can't be any text. And if you forget `:` then you may see `"Malformed application"`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had a Flask folder I was using in the place of ```"name_of_project"``` since it linked to other python files, but I guess it should have been just the name of the main application file.

Comment: it has to be name of main file and `:` with name of function which returns `Flask` instance. It can't be only name of main file.

Answer (score 1):

when defining your appname and the function that initialize your app with : dont put them into quotes('')

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30843887)